# C++ UDP two way client/server delivery

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

I'm building a UDP server for handling of position updates in a flight simulator (so, the packets will be rapid and guaranteed delivery isn't needed). The server creates and binds a UDP socket as per "session" in the server. The server then communicates the position information from the master to the viewers. This logic works (although, I currently have it coded to echo every message sent to it back to the sender, for testing) on a LAN (I had the server and client setup on the same system to test).

When I moved it to WAN, the client was no longer able to receive messages from the server, but the server received messages from the client. I am afraid it is a firewall/port blocking issue, however, I am coming here in hopes of either finding a different/correct way to do what I'm doing, or instructions on how I can escape the blocking.

The code for the server is as follows:

```
user newuser;
ommand = raw_connections[i].sockfd;     
sockaddr_in sin;
socklen_t len = sizeof(sin);
getsockname(raw_connections[i].sockfd, (sockaddr*)&sin, &len); //raw_connections is a vector of sockets that haven't yet authenticated
newuser.addr.sin_addr = sin.sin_addr;
newuser.addr.sin_family = sin.sin_family;
newuser.addr.sin_port = atoi(inp[4].c_str()); //the UDP port as specified by the client
flights[fpos].users.push_back(newuser); //fpos is the index in the vector
```

The above data is called as a result of a TCP socket between my program's UI and the system (the portion of that will handle user lists, administration, etc. - the UDP port is given to it from the position system, which generates it as follows:)

```
sockaddr_in service1;
service1.sin_family = AF_INET;
service1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
service1.sin_port = htons(0);

server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

mode = 1;
ioctlsocket(server_sock, FIONBIO, &mode);

soreuse = 1;
ioctlsocket(server_sock, SO_REUSEADDR, &soreuse);


sockaddr_in sin;
socklen_t len = sizeof(sin);
getsockname(server_sock, (sockaddr*)&sin, &len);
udpport = sin.sin_port; //the value of UDP port here is what's given to the client, and ultimately, the server
```

The sending portion of the server is this:

```
sockaddr_in addr;
int sz = sizeof(addr);
char* buff = new char[1024];            
int recvdf = recvfrom(gp->data_socket,buff,1024,NULL,(sockaddr*)&addr,&sz);
if (recvdf > 0) {
    cout << "got packet with size " << recvdf  << " on port " << addr.sin_port << endl;                             
    unsigned sz = gp->users.size();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        sendto(gp->data_socket, buff, recvdf, NULL, (sockaddr*)&gp->users[i].addr, sizeof(gp->users[i].addr));
    }
}
delete[] buff;
Sleep(1);
```

Finally, the interaction on the client side is this:

```
char* buffer = new char[1024];
int recvd = recvfrom(server_sock, buffer, 1024, NULL, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, &sockaddrsize);
if (recvd > 0) {
    int i = 282;
}
delete[] buffer;
sendto(server_sock, "test\0", 5, NULL, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, sockaddrsize);
```

Any suggestions to get it working? (The useless variable declared was used as a breakpoint in Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely your client is protected by a firewall that is blocking the incoming UDP packets from the Internet.  To get around that, you can either instruct the client's sysadmin to manually open up a hole in the firewall for incoming UDP on the port your server is sending the packets to (and if a NAT is involved, they'll need to set up port-forwarding on the NAT as well), or you can investigate [UDP hole-punching techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

Neither of the above techniques is particularly elegant or robust, though, so you might just want to have a fall-back mode for your software where all data is delivered via TCP stream.  Performance won't be quite as good, but sometimes it is better to have it "just work", and TCP will allow that.

Comment: I was afraid of that, however, isn't the firewall traditionally supposed to allow data receipt on a port it sent from?

Comment: I don't think there is any official behavior for what the firewall allows, so it will depend on what kind of firewall it is and what settings it is currently running with.  See some of the articles at the Wikipedia link for details on what sorts of rule-sets are common, but be aware that you can't rely on any particular firewall to follow the "common" rules, so even if you get hole-punching to work, you'll need a fallback mode if you want to work everywhere.

Comment: Aarrggh! That bothers me, the UDP packet delivery is so much more efficient for this...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your wording is very confusing: "UDP server" "viewer" "client" "the system" "the position system" ... . You wrote "I currently have it coded to echo every message sent to it back to the sender, for testing." However your "client" code only replies with a fixed string `"test\0"`.

When you have any doubts, you should write a minimal test code separate from your main project.

I assume the "viewer" is the "client."

You wrote

> The sending portion of the server is this:

```
int recvdf = recvfrom(gp->data_socket, ... );
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    sendto(gp->data_socket, ..., (sockaddr*)&gp->users[i].addr ... );
}
```

> Finally, the interaction on the client side is this:

```
int recvd = recvfrom(server_sock, ... );
sendto(server_sock, "test\0", ... (sockaddr*)&server_addr, ... );
```

But you also replied to @Jeremy

> I was afraid of that, however, isn't the firewall traditionally supposed to allow data receipt on a port it sent from?

There's a contradiction between these two.  Your server first send UDP datagrams to the clients and then the clients response back.  The first packet between your server and clients is sent from the server.  That's what I understood from your code.  You already knew this isn't going to work with typical firewalls.

Although @Jeremy is right in that each firewall is configured differently, most (home use) firewalls satisfy your assumption.  I suspect your code just doesn't utilize such a typical behavior of common firewalls.  If your "client" side can use, for example, Windows internet time synchronization which is in fact a UDP SNTP client and sends UDP datagram from an ephemeral source port to the time server, you should be able to receive UDP datagrams from your server as well.